# Can't install packages. Problem report ="get host by name failed in tcp_connect()"

Tags: beamer, packages, miktex, installing

I was trying to install beamer package from Miktex Package Manager but it appears a message Miktex Problem report ="get host by name failed in tcp_connect()". If I try Sychronize I have the same problem. Then I tried change Package Repository, I check packages shall be installed from the Internet, then Next and the same ="get host by name failed in tcp_connect()" problem appears (so no there is no list). Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by reinstall of current version